# pass multiple commands for FreeCADCmd.exe with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, freecad

how to pass multiple commands for FreeCADCmd.exe with python? For example this commands:

```
import FreeCAD
import Part
import Mesh
shape = Part.Shape()
shape.read('my_shape.step')
doc = App.newDocument('Doc')
pf = doc.addObject("Part::Feature","MyShape")
pf.Shape = shape
Mesh.export([pf], 'my_shape.stl')
```

here's my code but it gets stuck after first command, I mean "FreeCADCmd.exe":

```
os.chdir("D:\\program\\FreeCAD 0.19\\bin")
os.system("""FreeCADCmd.exe && import FreeCAD && import Part && import Mesh && shape = Part.Shape() && shape.read('D:\coupling_base.stp') && doc = App.newDocument('Doc') && pf = doc.addObject("Part::Feature","MyShape") && pf.Shape = shape && Mesh.export([pf], 'D:\z1.stl')""")
```

Looks like the && does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `os.system()` function runs a command in a terminal behind the scenes, which is often not a good way to call other programs. Instead you should use the subprocess module.

Try running the command you have inside your `os.system()` call in a terminal and you'll find it doesn't work there either. This is because it runs each command separated by an && one by one, rather than sending the subsequent commands into the first program.

In this case, it looks like FreeCADCmd.exe is a Python interpreter, so perhaps you could try storing the commands inside a Python script, then running that script?

Answer (score 0):

Put your commands in a file.  like  'myfile.py'
Then run

```
FreeCADCmd myfile.py
```